# styled-components - enzyme shallow snapshots

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme, styled-components, enzyme-to-snapshot

I am trying to find the solution how to avoid whole theme object in Jest snapshot.

I got, for Example, this simple test.

```
test("render", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Result item={item} />);
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

**Result.js**

```
const Title = styled.h3`
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors['primary']};    
`

Title.defaultProps = {
  theme: defautlTheme,
};


export default ({ item }) => (
 <div>
   <Title>{item.title}</Title>
   <p>{item.info}</p>
 </div>
);
```

**the Snapshot looks like:**

```
  exports[`render 1`] = `
       <div>
         <Result__Title
           theme={
             Object {
               "colors": Object {
                 "accent-100": "#000000",
                  "accent-200": "#000000",
                  "accent-300": "#000000",
                  "accent-400": "#000000",
                  "accent-500": "#f1c933",
                  "accent-600": "#000000",
                  "accent-700": "#ebbd10",
                  "accent-800": "#000000",
                  "accent-900": "#000000",
                  "black": "#000",
                  ....
```

Is possible to somehow to avoid this theme in snapshots with `shallow`.
Because it is very annoying if I change some color in theme, tests will fail in many other places.